# Given a range [a, b], how to find the x middle numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Given a range [$a$,$b$], how can I find the $x$ middle numbers?

For example:

[$1$,$10$]

Now I know that the middle $2$ numbers start with "$5$", but is there any way I can find the starting number, which in this case is "$5$", given a range doing some basic calculation$?$

Comment: What is a ‘middle number’?

Comment: Do you mean the middle point of the interval?

Comment: Can you give an example of what an $x$ middle number is?

Comment: So, *multisection*, then?

Comment: @lulu: the $x$ middle numbers are simply the numbers ($x$ of them) closest to the middle. (I assume that _numbers_ means _integers_ here.)

Comment: So...in your case, the strict middle would be $\frac {10+1}2=5.5$ so the two middle numbers would be $5,6$.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

If you meant the middle point of the interval then it is $\;M:=\cfrac{a+b}2\;$ . Why? Because (check this)

$$(1)\;\;a\le M\le B\;\;,\;\;\;(2)\;\;M-a=b-M$$

In fact, (2) above is the explanation for the formula for $\;M\;$ in the first line.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question! (See my comment to the OP.)

Comment: @TonyK Thank you.  It does if the asker meant the interval's middle number. *You* say he meant something else, yet the asker hasn't addressed any of these doubts, so how can we be sure? But for the very middle number, there is *no* number or numbers "closest" to the middle

Answer (score -1):

If $a$ and $b$ are integers, and you want the $x$ integers closest to the centre of $[a,b]$, then these are
$$\frac{a+b-x+1}{2},\frac{a+b-x}{2}+1,\ldots,\frac{a+b+x-1}{2}$$

assuming $a+b-x+1$ is even.

If $a+b-x+1$ is odd, then there is no unique solution. What are the two middle numbers in the range $[1,9]$, for instance?

Answer (score -1):

Simply we can use this formula like when we know the range
$$\frac{(a+ b)}{2}$$

> simplicity is the best policy

It is a range so in this case you can use 
$$\frac{(b)}{2}$$

> if range is an even number

Use $$\frac{(b+1)}{2}$$

> if range is an odd number

Above will give you the nth term which is your middle value of range(a, b)